# Creating multiple sequences with variable lengths with fixed increment?

Tags: r, sequence

I would like to create multiple sequences with variable lengths and a fixed increment between those sequences.
Like:

```
Seq.lengths<- c(2, 4, 2, 2, 2, 4)
increment <- 3

#Output should be a list like:

c(1:2, 5:8, 11:12, 15:16, 19:20, 23:26
)
```

I´ve tried "for" loops but, it doesn´t quite work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should be a smarter solution to this but an approach with `for` loop would look like -

```
Seq.lengths<- c(2, 4, 2, 2, 2, 4)
increment <- 3
result <- 1:Seq.lengths[1]

for(i in Seq.lengths[-1]) {
  val <- result[length(result)] + increment
  result <- c(result, val:(val + i - 1))
}

result
#[1]  1  2  5  6  7  8 11 12 15 16 19 20 23 24 25 26
```

If you want to store the output in a list -

```
Seq.lengths<- c(2, 4, 2, 2, 2, 4)
increment <- 3
result <- vector('list', length(Seq.lengths))
result[[1]] <- 1:Seq.lengths[1]

for(i in 2:length(Seq.lengths)){
  val <- result[[i-1]][length(result[[i-1]])] + increment
  result[[i]] <- val:(val + Seq.lengths[i] - 1)
}

result
#[[1]]
#[1] 1 2

#[[2]]
#[1] 5 6 7 8

#[[3]]
#[1] 11 12

#[[4]]
#[1] 15 16

#[[5]]
#[1] 19 20

#[[6]]
#[1] 23 24 25 26
```

Comment: That was completely sufficient. I was also thinking about using ´´´apply´´´ in some sort of way. Maybe that could improve the process?

Answer (score 0):

As you have `Seq.lenths`, another option could be to find the start of each sequence

```
Seq.lengths  <- c(2, 4, 2, 2, 2, 4)
increment <- 3
Seq.i  <-  seq_along(Seq.lengths[-1])
Seq.start <- cumsum(c(1, Seq.lengths[Seq.i] + (increment - 1)))
```

Then use `Map` and `seq` to get result

```
Map(function (x, y) seq(from = x, length.out = y), x = Seq.start, y = Seq.lengths)
[[1]]
[1] 1 2

[[2]]
[1] 5 6 7 8

[[3]]
[1] 11 12

[[4]]
[1] 15 16

[[5]]
[1] 19 20

[[6]]
[1] 23 24 25 26
```